# how do I keep immutability having a mutual dependency between 2 objects

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am having a problem with creating 2 immutable objects where both of them have a dependency on each other. Question: How do I solve this situation keeping these objects immutable?

```
public class One
{
    private readonly Another another;
    public One(Another another)
    {
        this.another = another;
    }
}

public class Another
{
    private readonly One one;
    public Another(One one)
    {
        this.one = one;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just create only one class?

Comment: what do you mean just one? i need both because of separation of concerns

Comment: Why do they need to be immutable?

Comment: i like immutability because it guarantees that once an object has been created it 's in a proper state which is some sort of the design time check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to do what you suggest, unless you at least allow for dependency injection on one of the classes, as follows:

```
public class One
{
    private readonly Another another;
    public One(Another another)
    {
        this.another = another;
    }
}

public class Another
{
    private readonly One one;
    public Another(One one)
    {
        this.one = one;
    }
    public Another() {}
    public setOne(One one)
    {
       this.one = one;
    }
}
```

You may then have to consider putting some sort of protection logic (Exceptions?) in Another.setOne() so that the One object can only be set once.

Also consider that you may have problems instantiating `Another` using the default constructor without initializing the `one` variable, in which case you may have to remove the readonly attribute and use the aforementioned logic in setOne()

**OR**

You could create the `One` class and internally have it create the `Another` class with a reference to `One`. This might increase the coupling between the two, but would do what you need, as folows:

```
public class One
{
    private readonly Another another;
    public One()
    {
        this.another = new Another(this);
    }
    public Another getAnother()
    {
        return this.another;
    }
}

public class Another
{
    private readonly One one;
    public Another(One one)
    {
        this.one = one;
    }
    public Another() {}
}

...

One one = new One();
Another another = one.getAnother();
```

Comment: it's c#, thanks, but setOne and Exception don't guarantee from doing stupid things

Comment: @bonomo, I added another option. Create the One class which internally will create the Another class with a reference to itself, and add a getAnother() method to One. Look at the new code above.

Comment: thanks Brady, another option looks like the closest I can get, I am accepting your answer