# Closely coupled C# classes in one module, how to improve this design?

Tags: c#, dependencies

I have inherited some code where every object in a particular namespace contains  other objects in the module as data fields.
Mostly, these references are passed into the constructor when the object is created. 
This results in a LOT of objects that contain references to the object that created them and in which they are stored as data fields.

For example, there is a wrapper object that wraps a lower layer.  This wrapper object holds a list of upper layer device objects.  But each upper layer device object holds a reference to the wrapper, which it needs to pass to other objects that it creates.
These other objects then use the wrapper object to call to the lower layers.

There is only one wrapper object, which gets passed around in the constructors of other objects, but it's not formally a singleton.

The (simplified) code below gives an idea of what it looks like:

```
using System;

    class UpperLayerManager 
{
    LowerLayerWrapper wrapperObject = new LowerLayerWrapper();
     UpperLayerManager()
    {
        wrapperObject.ULM = this;
    }

    void GetDevices()
    {
        wrapperObject.GetDevices();
    }
}


class UpperLayerDevice
{
    LowerLayerWrapper wrapperObject;
    UpperLayerOtherClass otherClass;

    UpperLayerDevice(LowerLayerWrapper wrapper)
    {
        this.wrapperObject = wrapper;
        this.otherClass = new UpperLayerOtherClass(wrapperObject);

    }

    //UpperLayerDevice currently doesn't make any calls into the lower layer
    // - the UpperLayerManager makes all device-related
    //calls via the LowerLayerWrapper.
}

class UpperLayerOtherClass
{

   LowerLayerWrapper wrapperObject;


     UpperLayerOtherClass(LowerLayerWrapper wrapper)
    {
        this.wrapperObject = wrapper;
    }

   void SomeOtherFunction()
   {
    this.wrapperObject.CallLowerLayer();
   }
}

class LowerLayerWrapper
{
    List<UpperLayerDevice> upperLayerDeviceList;

     UpperLayerManager ULM 
     {
        get;
        set;
     }

  void GetDevices()
  {
            UpperLayerDevice dev = new UpperLayerDevice(this);
                  //some calls to the lower layer here....

        upperLayerDeviceList.Add(dev);

    }

    void CallLowerLayer()
    {
        //here, some code that calls into the lower layer
    }
}
```

I want to tidy up the current coupling between the objects in this namespace.

What I thought up til now:
1. In some cases, use a similar solution to Brady's solution for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629336/how-do-i-keep-immutability-having-a-mutual-dependency-between-2-objects), and for example, only access UpperLayerDevice objects via the LowerLayerWrapper object that creates and holds them.
or
2. Make each object implement an interface to be used by the other objects in the module, instead of having them all containing each other as data fields.  Seems like overkill, normally I just use interfaces between software modules.
or
3. Make the objects that are only created once singletons, and let other objects access the singleton instead of passing references to constructors.  This reduces the number of object references that need to be passed around, but encourages singleton spaghetti?
or
4. Split classes into smaller classes, e.g.splitting the wrapper and creating some sort of device list holder object, so that the wrapper object doesn't need to be referenced by every other object.  I have already split off some wrapper functionality that wasn't completely wrapper-relevant, and thus reduced the number of calls to the wrapper object.  This doesn't actually reduce the number of objects that needs to be passed around, but it does prevent the ubiquitous objects that pop up everywhere.
or
5. Do nothing and go fishing (but it's hard for me to control information flow through the module when every object is mutually dependent upon every other object).

Obviously, I need to work with the current solution, rather than tearing it up and starting from scratch.

What's the best way forward?  Many thanks in advance for guidance.

Comment: You could try using an IOC container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many patterns for decoupling classes. A **Publisher-subscriber** pattern could do the trick in your case.

Consider implementing a message bus. This will tear up your current situation quite a bit, though but it will give you nice decoupling.

Suppose you want to call `GetDevices`. Instead of calling the actual wrapperobject's GetDevices, you can send a message to the message bus (perhaps with an identifier as parameter) and receive a callback with the response.

Instead of passing "hard" pointers to interfaces, you can use "soft" identifiers such as integers or strings to point to the right object (or layer).

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  You mean, basically send a load of events flying around, instead of direct function calls?  And get returned information via another event?  That would certainly be an improvement on the current dependency.

Comment: Indeed. No matter if you call it "event" or "message" :) I'd prefer to build a message bus where objects can register themselves (as a publisher and/or subscriber). This way you can even have multiple objects taking action on a single message. In the case you need to receive a response to your message, you could add a callback function as a parameter to the message. Maybe even in a async/await manner.

Comment: I'm tending towards using this solution to reduce the number of dependencies, but not trying to eliminate all dependencies.  For example, there are some small classes where the dependency is not mutual - they can stay as data fields in other objects, because that is simple.  But I will try the message bus to get rid of the mutual dependencies.  Thank you for your reply.